# After Update android studio to 2.2, I can't generate APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating Android studio to 2.2, I can't generate APK. It was working before update android studio. I am stuck from last 2 days. I used 4 project as a library `circleindicator` `:ffmpeg4android_lib`  `libraryCalender`  `libraryGridView`.   Please guide me How can solve?

Error message is :

```
Information:Gradle tasks
[:app:generateDebugSources,
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
:app:mockableAndroidJar, 
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 

:circleindicator:generateDebugSources, 
:circleindicator:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, 
:circleindicator:mockableAndroidJar, 
:circleindicator:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 

:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateDebugSources, 
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, 
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mockableAndroidJar, 
:ffmpeg4android_lib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 

:libraryCalender:generateDebugSources, 
:libraryCalender:mockableAndroidJar, 
:libraryCalender:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 
:libraryCalender:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, 

:libraryGridView:generateDebugSources, 
:libraryGridView:mockableAndroidJar, 
:libraryGridView:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 
:libraryGridView:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

my gradle file as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.toodapp.socialmedia"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.4"
    ndk {
        abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        //abiFilter "x86"
    }
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            className 'com.example.MyProcessor'

            // Arguments are optional.
            arguments = [foo: 'bar']
        }
    }

}

signingConfigs {
    config {
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
productFlavors {
}

}
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile project(':libraryCalender')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile project(':libraryGridView')
compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
}
```

And build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

And gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Oct 14 11:51:58 IST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Comment: did u clean your project?

Comment: yes. so many times. also tried with  restart studio